# cosmos fiware curl returns curl(52) Empty reply from server

Tags: curl, fiware-cosmos

I try this command

```
curl -L     http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/souleime/file1         &user.name=souleime" -H "X-Auth-Token: *****************" -O
```

and I get curl(52) Empty reply from server. My file exists on the HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to read my file 
    curl -i -L "http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/souleime/file1?op=open&user.name=souleime" -H "X-Auth-Token: ****************"

?op=open was my problem

Comment: Yes, the kind of operation must be added to the URL. The API is the same than the WebHDFS original one (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html), but with the addition of the OAuth2 token header.